# Smaller toolbar when no primary items in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way to decrease the height of toolbar in xamarin.forms when there are no primary items present, for Windiws phone. 
The original windows phone app was build directly for wp, not with xamarin.forms, so there was an option ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal" which accomplished it.

See attached pictures for a better idea.

First image is classic WP app, the second is Xamarin.Forms WP app.

[image: Classic WP app]

[image: Xamarin.Forms WP app]

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom style for the `FormsCommandBar` control. See the default [here on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4df66d139f8128486b3e34e1c206413abd1babd5/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FormsCommandBarStyle.xaml). You can create a copy of the default `Style` in your UWP project and modify the setter of `ClosedDisplayMode` from `Compact` to `Minimal`.

```
<Setter Property="ClosedDisplayMode" Value="Minimal"/>
```

However, if you want to set the `Minimal` size only when `Compact`, you would have to create a custom class deriving from `FormsCommandBar` and then implement [custom `Style` for `Page`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/3da9a4cca74e694e1e000a7b92727cf413aba478/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/PageControlStyle.xaml) to use your own type instead of the built-in one.